# Operations on n-th argument of curried functions in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, currying, partial-application

I'm working with a lot of curried functions, taking similar arguments, but not quite. For this reason I would find very beneficial to have a way to perform transposition, application and composition of n-th argument, as well as the 'final' result. Example:

```
val f :X=>Y=>W=>Z
def compose1[A](w :A=>Y) :X=>A=>W=>Z
def transpose1 :X=>W=>Y=>Z
def apply1(y :Y) :X=>W=>Z
```

It can be easily accomplished for a fixed value of n with something like this:

```
implicit class Apply2[X, Y, Z](private val f :X=>Y=>Z) extends AnyVal {
    def transpose :Y=>X=>Z = { y :Y => x :X => f(x)(y) }
    def provide(y :Y) :X=>Z ={ x :X => f(x)(y) }
    def compose[A](y :A=>Y) : X=>A=>Z = { x :X => a :A => f(x)(y(a)) }
    def apply[A, B]()(implicit ev :Z <:< (A=>B)) :Apply3[X, Y, A, B] = new Apply3[X, Y, A, B]((x :X) => (y :Y) => ev(f(x)(y)))
}
```

But of course I don't welcome the idea of copy-&-pasting 22 versions of this class. I can also quite easily do it for the last argument with a type class,
but the solution that would be similarily succint to scala's underscore notation for partial application of non-curried function eludes me. I feel it should be possible to achive the following:

```
val f :A=>B=>C=>D=>E=>F
val c = f()().compose( (x :X) => new C(x)) :A=>B=>X=>D=>E=>F
val t = f()().transpose :A=>B=>D=>C=>E=>F
val s = f()().set(new C()) :A=>B=>D=>E=>F
```

via an implicit conversion to some `Apply` which provides a recursive `apply()` method returning a nested `Apply` instance.

When all types are known, the brute solution of converting to a HList and back works, but shapless' dependency is a bit of a two-edged sword.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "sets traps in generic code"? In my experience I always wind up feeling more "trapped" by implicit conversions than by type class-based solutions.

Comment: First and foremost, path dependent types; as powerful as they are, they are also the largest source of my frustration (and perplexion about compiler errors in the past). Second, IntelliJ doesn't understand shapeless very well. Third, me neither... Not a drawback of the library and I use HLists very often, but I am a bit reluctuant to have magic going on around run-down-the-mill production code.

Comment: Edited out remark about shapeless as I didn't realise it came as unconstructive critisism while the problem is between the chair and the keyboard...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, my mind still itches but I finally got it! Most difficult programming task I did in a while, though. If anyone has suggestions for improvement (including naming, notation and generally syntax) I'm all ears.

```
/** Represents a partially applied, curried function `F` which is of the form `... X => A`,
  * where X is the type of the first argument after (partial) application.
  * Provides methods for manipulating functions `F` around this argument.
  * @tparam F type of the manipulated function in a curried form (non-empty sequence of single argument lists)
  * @tparam C[G] result of mapping partial result `(X=>A)` of function `F` to `G`.
  * @tparam X type of the argument represented by this instance
  * @tparam A result type of function F partially applied up to and including argument X
  */
abstract class Curry[F, C[G], X, A](private[funny] val f :F) { prev =>
    /** Result of partial application of this function F up to and including parameter `X`. */
    type Applied = A
    /** Replace X=>A with G as the result type of F. */
    type Composed[G] = C[G]
    /** A function which takes argument `W` instead of `X` at this position. */
    type Mapped[W] = Composed[W=>A]


    /** Provide a fixed value for this argument, removing it from the argument list.
      * For example, the result of `Curry{a :Any => b :Byte => c :Char => s"&dollar;a&dollar;b&dollar;c" }().set(1.toByte)`
      * (after inlining) would be a function `{a :Any => c :Char => s"&dollar;a&dollar;{1.toByte}&dollar;c" }`.
      */
    def set(x :X) :Composed[A] = applied[A](_(x))

    /** Change the type of this argument by mapping intended argument type `W` to `X` before applying `f`.
      * For example, given a function `f :F &lt;:&lt; D=>O=>X=>A` and `x :W=>X`, the result is `{d :D => o :O => w :W => f(d)(o)(x(w)) }`.
      */
    def map[W](x :W=>X) :Composed[W=>A] = applied[W=>A]{ r :(X=>A) => (w :W) => r(x(w)) }

    /** Map the result of partial application of this function up to argument `X` (not including).
      * For example, if `F =:= K=>L=>X=>A`, the result is a function `{k :K => l :L => map(f(k)(l)) }`.
      * @param map function taking the result of applying F up until argument `X`.
      * @return resul
      */
    def applied[G](map :((X => A) => G)) :Composed[G]

    /** If the result of this partial application is a function `A &lt;:&lt; Y=>Z`, swap the order of arguments
      * in function `F` from `=>X=>Y=>` to `=>Y=>X=>`.
      */
    def transpose[Y, Z](implicit ev :A<:<(Y=>Z)) :Composed[Y=>X=>Z] = applied[Y=>X=>Z] {
        r :(X=>A) => y :Y => x :X => ev(r(x))(y)
    }


    /** Skip to the next argument, i.e return an instance operating on the result of applying this function to argument `X`. */
    def apply[Y, Z]()(implicit ev :this.type<:<Curry[F, C, X, Y=>Z])  = new NextArg[F, C, X, Y, Z](ev(this))

    /** Skip to the next argument, i.e return an instance operating on the result of applying this function to argument `X`.
      * Same as `apply()`, but forces an implicit conversion from function types which `apply` wouldn't.
      */
    def __[Y, Z](implicit ev :this.type<:<Curry[F, C, X, Y=>Z])  = new NextArg[F, C, X, Y, Z](ev(this))
}


/** Operations on curried functions. */
object Curry {
    type Self[G] = G
    type Compose[C[G], X] = { type L[G] = C[X=>G] }

    /** Extension methods for modifying curried functions at their first argument (and a source for advancing to subsequent arguments. */
    @inline def apply[A, B](f :A=>B) :Arg0[A, B] = new Arg0(f)

    /** Implicit conversion providing extension methods on curried function types. Same as `apply`, but doesn't pollute namespace as much. */
    @inline implicit def ImplicitCurry[A, B](f :A=>B) :Arg0[A, B] = new Arg0(f)

    /** Operations on the first argument of this function. */
    class Arg0[X, Y](x :X=>Y) extends Curry[X=>Y, Self, X, Y](x) {

        def applied[G](map: (X=>Y) => G) :G = map(f)
    }

    class NextArg[F, C[G], X, Y, A](val prev :Curry[F, C, X, Y=>A]) extends Curry[F, (C Compose X)#L, Y, A](prev.f) {

        override def applied[G](map: (Y => A) => G): prev.Composed[X => G] =
            prev.applied[X=>G] { g :(X=>Y=>A) => x :X => map(g(x)) }
    }
}


def f :Byte=>Short=>Int=>Long=>String = ???

import Curry.ImplicitCurry

f.set(1.toByte) :(Short=>Int=>Long=>String)
f.map((_:String).toByte) :(String=>Short=>Int=>Long=>String)
f.__.set(1.toShort) :(Byte=>Int=>Long=>String)
Curry(f)().map((_:String).toShort) : (Byte=>String=>Int=>Long=>String)
```